# TextWatcher on EditText Android

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have 2 edittext and i want to set the second edittext to 0 and make it inactivated if the value of the first edittext is lower than 10. I used TextWatcher but i have a stack overflow error when running. Can anyone help me with this ??
my code is as following:

```
    qteDev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_qtedev);
    qte = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_qte);
    qte.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {           
         if(qte.getText().toString().equals(""))
             return ;
         int l = qte.getText().length();
         if (l == 1) {
             qteDev.setText("0");
             qteDev.setClickable(false);
             qteDev.setEnabled(false);
             qteDev.setActivated(false);
         }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post the error (log-cat)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your `afterTextChanged` method:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) < 10) {
        secondEditText.setText(0);
        secondEditText.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: it still make the same error in the line secondEditText.setText("0"); i will solve it my way by putting 0 as default value and testing just the activation. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your afterTextChanged method

```
qteDev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_qtedev);
qte = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_qte);
qte.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(s.toString().length() < 10){
        qteDev.setText("0");
        qteDev.setEnable(false);
    }
}
```

if any question, put any comment. thanks